# Invalid Scope for BigCommerce Oauth for my app - store_v2_transactions_read_only

Tags: bigcommerce

My app is an approved hidden app in BigCommerce that has all of the scopes selected in the MyApp Technical page. Unfortunately, when I try to oAuth into a user, the following scope 'store_v2_transactions_read_only' returns an 'invalid scope' message. If I take that scope out, the other scopes (for read_only orders, customers, etc.) work fine and I can successfully connect an account using Oauth with my app.

The scope 'store_v2_transactions_read_only' is found in the documentation in the list of scopes here: https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/#oauth-scopes96. But making the request to connect an account using that scope returns 'invalid_scope' and I can't access user transaction data. Again, all other scopes work, and I have them all selected in the app technical page in the developer portal.

Working in node and using axios to get the token with the oauth code. This list of scopes works:

`scope: 'store_v2_customers_read_only store_v2_information_read_only store_v2_orders_read_only store_v2_products_read_only'`

The moment I add `store_v2_transactions_read_only` it returns 'invalid scope', even thought that is the string stated in the docs. It is the same error that shows if I misspell any of the scopes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you're passing in the `context` in your query string. At the time of writing the API will send back an `Invalid scope(s).` error seemingly only when you request `store_v2_transactions_read_only` without this query param. Other scopes seem to work fine, as you've noticed, if this param is not sent.

Answer (score 1):

Can't comment, because I don't have 50 karma, but adding the context to the POST call in postman from the correct answer fixed this issue for me. I had been dealing with it for some time and there isn't a lot of documentation on the BigCommerce side in other forum posts.

I am using the x-www-form-urlencoded params with:

KEY: context
VALUE: stores/abcdefg

The abcdefg is the actual store number/id in the exact format it came in from the callback.